# Flurry SDK wont initialise on session start

Tags: java, android, flurry

when i add the flurry code into my activity it crashes saying flurry sdk not initialised, ive checked to make sure that the library is added to the project library, below is my code and logcat, it also has the import flurry in the activity

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this,"YOUR_API_KEY" );
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

logcat

```
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity       ComponentInfo{com.stephenh.daytrack.daytrackstephenh/com.stephenh.daytrack.daytrackstephenh.PageActivities.Exercises}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Flurry SDK must be initialized before starting a session
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2263)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Flurry SDK must be initialized before starting a session
        at com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.onStartSession(SourceFile:328)
        at com.stephenh.daytrack.daytrackstephenh.PageActivities.Exercises.onStart(Exercises.java:61)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1172)
```

Comment: What version of Flurry are you using? Is it v5.0.0? That version has conflicts with initializing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its Crashes because FlurryAgent is not initialized and you are trying to start the session. 
So, Initialize FlurryAgent like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {

   super.onCreate();

   // configure Flurry
   FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(false);

   // init Flurry
   FlurryAgent.init(this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY);
 }
}
```

Later you can start and stop session as shown:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "YOUR_API_KEY");
}

@Override

protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();     
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

Comment: This answer combined with the answer @ademar111190 gave below would make a great answer :)

Comment: @Srikant P how to find "Ad space name" i am confused about this. when i run my code the getting this error "unkonwn ad space name" plz help me

Answer (score 5):

The method `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context, key);` is deprecated you need call first the method `FlurryAgent.init(context, key);` and after `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context);`

Comment: Do I need to Initialise Furry in my all activities? as I am using FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context, key); on my each Activity of my Application?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela You need call the init method just one time in your application session, but in each activity you need call the onStartSession.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Well If I initialise it on my Activity Session inspite of Application Session. What would be the difference? As I am initialising in every Activity, would it create me any problem?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela I don't know, but I think that if you do it, the flurry will not create the navigation tree.

Comment: well it also creates the Navigation Tree for the Application.

Answer (score 0):

I was running `FlurryAgent.init(this, "myapikey");` in my on launch Activity and I got a exception on the `onStart` of my subsequent activity.

So I just called `FlurryAgent.init(this, "myapikey");` again. No issues as now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the last couple of Flurry updates to comply with GDPR they have [depreciated the init function](http://flurry.github.io/flurry-android-sdk/deprecated-list.html), and [SDK jar files](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android-manual/) as well. You can now init flurry by just implementing the FlurryAgent.Builder class. Since jar files are depreciated and will be removed soon you now should inject the dependency into your apps build gradle file.

Example of build gradle injection (use 11.1.0 or higher sdk, don't use sdk 11.0.0 because it was bugged with an initialization with an activity context error)

```
repositories {
jcenter()
google()
}
dependencies {

implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:11.1.0@aar'
implementation 'com.flurry.android:ads:11.1.0@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
```

And here is an example of using the FlurryAgent.Builder to init Flurry:

```
new FlurryAgent.Builder().withLogEnabled(true).withLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE).withCaptureUncaughtExceptions(true)
        .withContinueSessionMillis(10000).withConsent(new FlurryConsent(true, consentStrings))
            .build(this, flurryAppId);
FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this);
```

To get the consent strings to add to the builder for GDPR compliance I had to implement the [privacy dash project](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework) over on github.

Comment: Hi. I am not sure how to implement the formation of the consent strings: if I use the Readme instructions, I still have to assign: cmpId, cmpVersion, consentScreenID, maxVendorId, etc. Do you actually have the values of these variables, or even better, the consent strings, for Flurry ads? Can you send me a copy? Thanks